# How to connect to multiple MySQL databases as per the header in REST API request

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, multi-tenant

I'm creating a multi tenant spring boot - JPA application.

In this application, I want to connect to MySQL Databases using DB name which is sent through API request as header.

I checked many multi tenant project samples online but still can't figure out a solution.

Can anyone suggest me a way to do this?

Comment: this sounds like a potential security hole to me. What's the reason for doing that? It's arguably a design flaw too: A client of the API shouldn't know or care anything about databases at all. Surely, the identity of the user making the request (or some similar factor or combination of factors) would determine the database which the API decides to use.

Comment: Thank you for response. I know I sound like implementing an app with no security. But this design is just to start the app. We are planed to make db connections as per the request but not to get DB name and creds from request.

Comment: Not sure I follow your logic but ok. Anyway what is giving you trouble exactly? Send the request with a suitable header? Retrieving the header value from the request? Opening a DB connection using a variable for the DB name? It's unclear precisely what the issue really is.

Comment: I just figured it out how to do it, and just posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/wmeints/spring-multi-tenant-demo

Following this logic, I can solve it now. Some of the versions need to be upgraded and the codes as well.

- Spring Boot version have changed.

  org.springframework.boot
      spring-boot-starter-parent
      2.1.0.RELEASE
- Mysql version has been removed.
- And some small changed in `MultitenantConfiguration.java`

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class MultitenantConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private DataSourceProperties properties;

  /**
   * Defines the data source for the application
   * @return
   */
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(
          prefix = "spring.datasource"
  )
  public DataSource dataSource() {
      File[] files = Paths.get("tenants").toFile().listFiles();
      Map<Object,Object> resolvedDataSources = new HashMap<>();

      if(files != null) {
          for (File propertyFile : files) {
              Properties tenantProperties = new Properties();
              DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

              try {
                  tenantProperties.load(new FileInputStream(propertyFile));

                  String tenantId = tenantProperties.getProperty("name");

                  dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName())
                          .url(tenantProperties.getProperty("datasource.url"))
                          .username(tenantProperties.getProperty("datasource.username"))
                          .password(tenantProperties.getProperty("datasource.password"));

                  if (properties.getType() != null) {
                      dataSourceBuilder.type(properties.getType());
                  }

                  resolvedDataSources.put(tenantId, dataSourceBuilder.build());
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  return null;
              }
          }
      }

      // Create the final multi-tenant source.
      // It needs a default database to connect to.
      // Make sure that the default database is actually an empty tenant database.
      // Don't use that for a regular tenant if you want things to be safe!
      MultitenantDataSource dataSource = new MultitenantDataSource();
      dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDataSource());
      dataSource.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources);

      // Call this to finalize the initialization of the data source.
      dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();

      return dataSource;
  }

  /**
   * Creates the default data source for the application
   * @return
   */
  private DataSource defaultDataSource() {
      DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
              .driverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName())
              .url(properties.getUrl())
              .username(properties.getUsername())
              .password(properties.getPassword());

      if(properties.getType() != null) {
          dataSourceBuilder.type(properties.getType());
      }

      return dataSourceBuilder.build();
  }
  ```

  }

This change is here due to the `DataSourceBuilder` has been moved to another path and its constructor has been changed.

- Also changed the MySQL driver class name in `application.properties` like this

  spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Not sure how different it is from my solution except for the fact I didn't provide exact solution for building different data sources.

Comment: This is very rude. First get an idea from other person, accept their answer, then answer your own and accept it. Well played.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AbstractRoutingDataSource` to achieve this. `AbstractRoutingDataSource` requires information to know which actual `DataSource` to route to(referred to as *Context*), which is provided by `determineCurrentLookupKey()` method.  Using example from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source).

Define *Context* like:

```
public enum ClientDatabase {
    CLIENT_A, CLIENT_B
}
```

Then you need to define Context Holder which will be used in `determineCurrentLookupKey()`

```
public class ClientDatabaseContextHolder {

    private static ThreadLocal<ClientDatabase> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void set(ClientDatabase clientDatabase) {
        Assert.notNull(clientDatabase, "clientDatabase cannot be null");
        CONTEXT.set(clientDatabase);
    }

    public static ClientDatabase getClientDatabase() {
        return CONTEXT.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        CONTEXT.remove();
    }
}
```

Then you can extend `AbstractRoutingDataSource` like below:

```
public class ClientDataSourceRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return ClientDatabaseContextHolder.getClientDatabase();
    }
}
```

Finally, `DataSource` bean configuration:

```
@Bean
public DataSource clientDatasource() {
    Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
    DataSource clientADatasource = clientADatasource();
    DataSource clientBDatasource = clientBDatasource();
    targetDataSources.put(ClientDatabase.CLIENT_A, 
      clientADatasource);
    targetDataSources.put(ClientDatabase.CLIENT_B, 
      clientBDatasource);

    ClientDataSourceRouter clientRoutingDatasource 
      = new ClientDataSourceRouter();
    clientRoutingDatasource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    clientRoutingDatasource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(clientADatasource);
    return clientRoutingDatasource;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Reply, Your solution seems to be working correct, but I found a better way for this. I'm posting it now.